# how get random row from =>1 in table of database in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, random

this is my PHP code, How can I get randomly row from 'featured'=>1 in table of database in MySQL?
which part of my below code should change?

`$featured_movie        =   $this->db->get_where('movie', array('featured'=>1))->row();`

Comment: Are you using a framework (looks like codeigniter?)? A database interface wrapper?

Comment: What is the class which this method is in? Are you using a framework?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton yes

Comment: @KamyarMirzavaziri Yes

Comment: @Ashkan You need to give the name of framework in your question.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton this code selecting the row from the less id. I want it select randomly from all id's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to order the query by `rand()`, and limit the query to a single return to speed it up (this is done by using the 3rd parameter of `get_where`).

```
$featured_movie = $this->db->order_by('featured', 'RANDOM')->get_where('movie', ['featured' => 1], 1)->row();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried it but it doesn't work at all.

Comment: This is the error log ---> Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_result::order_by()

Comment: @Ashkan Ah I see. From the documentation, it looks like `get_where()` has to be the last call in the chain. Let me know if the current code works. You may have to do `$featured_movie->row()` separately.

Comment: `$featured_movie        =   $this->db->order_by('featured', 'RANDOM')->get_where('movie', array('featured'=>1))->row();`